# Crossdomain Ajax with google places

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp, google-places-api

I have a problem with **Google Places API**. I tried to send a place to google but i got an 400 Error.

```
  var send = {
    "location": {
      "lat": 25.696183,
      "lng": 8.136408
    },
    "accuracy": 25,
    "name": "Google Shoes!",
    "types": ["Schuhgeschäft"],
    "language": "de"
  }
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=false&key={KEY}',
    type: 'POST',
    data: send,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    success:function(json){
         alert("Success");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }
  });
```

In the debug console I got this Error:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=false&key={KEY}&callback=jQuery183005409403680823743_1355988904458&location%5Blat%5D=48.696183&location%5Blng%5D=8.136408&accuracy=25&name=Google+Shoes!&types%5B%5D=Schuhgesch%C3%A4ft&language=de&_=1355988904466 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: You don't provide your API key instead of the placeholder {KEY}.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in the actual key.  Plus, I don't think they support JSONP or POSTs.